# RCP E4 @UIEventTopic not called

Tags: java, eclipse, events, rcp, e4

I am new to RCP Eclipse 4 and read a lot of tutorials so far. We have to do a Project work for University so I need to get in touch with it.

We are coding a really small application with JPA/EclipseLink and HSQLDB which is working fine already. Also calling and displaying Parts in RCP is already working. We did get some code-base with which we should work. I did some research and now we are able to display our parts through commands/handlers and partdescriptors.

Now is the time for bringing some Information from part A to part B. We already found the Version of inserting data into the context via

```
context.getParent().set( " NAME " , object)
```

But i dont really like this Version because when i use the @Named convention and all parts with @Named("NAME") will get called each time I change the contexts properties.

Another method I found and I liked a lot was, working with Events. http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse4EventSystem/article.html#eventsystem  described it really well. But the problem is, its just not working.

ClientSearchPart.java:

```
@Override
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
    broker.send("a", "testtest");
}


@Inject @Optional
public void getEvent(@UIEventTopic("a")String s) {
    System.out.println("ClientsSearch: "+s);
}
```

ClientDetailPart.java:

```
@Inject @Optional
void getEvent(@UIEventTopic("a") String k) {
    System.out.println(k);
}
```

I am trying to send a String from ClientSearchPart to ClientDetailPart. When widgetSelected is performed, getEvent() from ClientSearchPart.java is called and prints out "ClientsSearch: testest" while ClientDetailPart is never called!

I can't help myself anymore. Wheres my mistake? I am trying this now for over 3 hours and dont really get a clue why it isn't working.

Answer (score -1):

I can't tell exactly what is wrong but my first guess would be, that the method in your `ClientDetailPart` should be public. The injection framework is only able to call public methods.

Is your `ClientDetailPart` in another bundle? If so, did you also add the required bundle which are needed for DI?

Comment: No, that's wrong information - the injection framework is able to call private & protected methods as well. Actually it's best practice to make injection methods who should not be called from outside protected or private.